# How to create a new ref for each component instance

Tags: reactjs, react-ref

How to create a ref for each instance of a component

I've extracted some code into it's own component. The component is a PlayWhenVisible animation component that plays/stops the animation depending on whether the element is in view.

I'm creating a ref inside the component constructor but since I'm getting some lag when using 2 instances of the component I'm wondering if I should create the refs outside the component and pass them in as props or whether there's a way to create a new instance for each compoenent instance.

```
import VisibilitySensor from "react-visibility-sensor";
class PlayWhenVisible extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.animation = React.createRef();
    this.anim = null;
  }
render() {
    return (
      <VisibilitySensor
        scrollCheck
        scrollThrottle={100}
        intervalDelay={8000}
        containment={this.props.containment}
        onChange={this.onChange}
        minTopValue={this.props.minTopValue}
        partialVisibility={this.props.partialVisibility}
        offset={this.props.offset}
      >
        {({ isVisible }) => {
          isVisible ? this.anim.play() : this.anim && this.anim.stop();
          return (
            // <div style={style}>
            <i ref={this.animation} id="animation" className={this.props.class} />
          );
        }}
      </VisibilitySensor>
    );
}
}
```

Comment: It;s unclear what's the problem is. Each PlayWhenVisible instance gets its own `animation` ref.

Comment: Can you please share complete code for better understanding ?

Comment: If you're getting lag, it's not because of calling `createRef()`.

Comment: @estus I was wondering whether the two references might clash because they'd be using the same name, but there won't be a reason for that since they're encapsulated.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was caused by the VisibilityChecker component which was overflowing the container and causing it to be erratic when firing.